# 2 by 2 coupled ODEs with non-constant coefficients

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplace-transform

I have the following coupled linear DE that I wish to solve. However, their coefficients are non-constant, namely, I wish to solve

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\begin{bmatrix}y(x) \newline z(x)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}C_{1}+C_{2}x^{2} & C_{3} \newline D_{3} & D_{1}+D_{2}x^{2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y(x) \newline z(x)\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $C_{j}$ and $D_{j}$ are constants (not $x$ dependent). I tried solving it the old fashion way by finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix, but they became complicated and seems intractable. I was thinking about Laplace transforms but I would have to do two Laplace transforms for the $y(x)$ and $z(x)$ equations respectively and that doesn't seem like it will be useful. How should I go about solving the preceding equations?

Comment: Have you tried to work in the diagonal basis of your matrix $A$ ? The generator of the new differential equation will be $S'S^{-1} + D$, with $D$ the diagonalized version of $A$ and $S$ the transformation matrix between the canonical basis and the eigenbasis of $A$. Sometimes it can decouple the two equations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't expect to find any 'nice' solutions for general values of the constants. Note that in the particular case $C_1=C_2=0$ and $C_3=1$, the system is equivalent to the second order ODE
$$y''-(D_1+D_2x^2)y'-D_3y=0$$
which is a case of an [Triconfluent Heun equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun_function). Note that it's solutions (called Heun functions) are, in some sense, more complicated than [Hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) as their group of symmetries is of order 196 (in opposite of 24) and their coefficients in the power series solutions do not obeys simple two-term recurrence relations (in opposite of what happens with the larger class of [Generalized hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function)).